# How to join two maps into one in r?

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2

I am wondering if there is a way to join two maps of class "sp" into one.

For example Sweden + Norway, there is a code (shp data were downloaded from: http://www.gadm.org/country):

```
library(maptools)

mapa_shp_swe <- readShapePoly("C:/r/SWE_adm/SWE_adm0.shp")
mapa_map_swe <- fortify(mapa_shp_swe)

swe <- ggplot(mapa_map_swe, aes(x = long, y = lat, group=group)) + 
  geom_path(size=1) +
  theme_bw()

mapa_shp_nor <- readShapePoly("C:/r/NOR_adm/NOR_adm0.shp")
mapa_map_nor <- fortify(mapa_shp_nor)

nor <- ggplot(mapa_map_nor, aes(x = long, y = lat, group=group)) + 
  geom_path(size=1) +
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: You need to separate your question #2 from the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I tend to use the `spRbind()` function in the `rgdal` package, because I tend to have this loaded when working with shapefiles anyway.

```
# ensure shapefiles have unique ids
n <- length(slot(mapa_shp_swe, "polygons"))
newShape <- spChFIDs(mapa_shp_nor, as.character(n))

# the actual join
newShape <- spRbind(newShape, mapa_shp_swe)

# you can then write it if you wish
writeOGR(sweNor, dsn = "shapes/", layer = "newShape",
         driver = "ESRI Shapefile")
```

Which should write a new shapefile called `sweNor` with both original shapefiles merged in the `shapes/` directory.

As for plotting the cities, as @cmbarbu points out this should really be asked as a separate question, but you could try adding the following code:

```
ggplot(newShape, aes(x = long, y = lat, group=group)) + 
    geom_path(size=1) + 
    geom_point(data = cities, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    theme_bw()
```

I haven't tested this yet so there's no guarantee!

Comment: thank you @Phil! last code (plotting the cities) doesn't work but I post it as a separate question

Comment: No worries. When you post the question, link back to this one so people can see the context. Also, comment here (@Phil) and I'll keep an eye out.

Comment: Answer for second question (@Phil): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29240134/how-to-add-points-into-map

Answer (score 1):

You need first to make sure that the polygon names (`row.names`) are different:

```
 > row.names(mapa_shp_swe)
 [1] "0"
 > row.names(mapa_shp_nor)
 [1] "0"

 mapa_shp_swe <- spChFIDs(mapa_shp_swe,"1") # set polygon name 
 > row.names(mapa_shp_swe)
 [1] "1"
```

Then you can simply bind them:

```
 peninsula <- rbind(mapa_shp_nor,mapa_shp_swe)
```

Comment: swe <- spChFIDs(swe,"1") doesn't work. Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :   unable to find an inherited method for function ‘spChFIDs’ for signature ‘"gg", "character"’ @cmbarbu

Comment: make sure to run spChFIDs on the sp maps, directly imported from shp, not on the "fortified" maps. I edited the answer to make it clearer.