# How to add points into map?

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2

There is the first part of the question: [How to join two maps into one in r?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29233480/how-to-join-two-maps-into-one-in-r)

Complete code to bind two maps SWE and NOR (shp data were downloaded from: http://www.gadm.org/country):

```
library(maptools)

mapa_shp_swe <- readShapePoly("C:/r/SWE_adm/SWE_adm0.shp")
mapa_map_swe <- fortify(mapa_shp_swe)

swe <- ggplot(mapa_map_swe, aes(x = long, y = lat, group=group)) + 
  geom_path(size=1) +
  theme_bw()

mapa_shp_nor <- readShapePoly("C:/r/NOR_adm/NOR_adm0.shp")
mapa_map_nor <- fortify(mapa_shp_nor)

nor <- ggplot(mapa_map_nor, aes(x = long, y = lat, group=group)) + 
  geom_path(size=1) +
  theme_bw()

n <- length(slot(mapa_shp_swe, "polygons"))
newShape <- spChFIDs(mapa_shp_nor, as.character(n))

newShape2 <- spRbind(newShape, mapa_shp_swe)

map <- ggplot(newShape2, aes(x = long, y = lat, group=group)) + 
  geom_path(size=1) +
  theme_bw()
```

How to add cities (as points) to this map?
This doesn't work:

```
cities <- data.frame(ID = c("stockholm","Oslo"),
                     x = c(59.32, 59.95),
                     y = c(18.06, 10.75))

ggplot(newShape2, aes(x = long, y = lat, group=group)) + 
  geom_path(size=1) +
  geom_point(data = cities, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: How does the lat and long values of `newShape2` look like? I find no apparent error in your code which leads one to suspect that your original shapefiles are in another coordinate system than ordinary lat/long degrees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three things:

1. I think that you messed up what is long and what is lat. Reverse the order of x and y in your `geom_point`
2. Put the group aestethic into `geom_path`since it is not needed for any other geom at this point.
3. Add some color and size to your points the default black might be hard to spot.

The following does probably work:

```
ggplot(newShape2, aes(x = long, y = lat)) + 
   geom_path(aes(group=group), size=1) +
   geom_point(data = cities, aes(x = y, y = x),col="red", size=5)+
   theme_bw()
```

Lycka till!